# Return to same page after pagereference

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, outputlink, commandlink

I am having a VF page that generates content as excel, which I am calling from another page as a commandLink. The problem I am facing is when I click the commandLink, the current page becomes blank.

I could use outputLink and give the page name and parameters directly, but I do not want to expose name of page that generates the content as excel.

Could someone please help on this?

Comment: Security through obscurity? What do you hope to accomplish by hiding the URL?

Comment: The page is on communities and URL will contain SFDC id as parameter. So wouldn't wish to display the id in the first place.